# Question about probability equation

Tags: probability, conditional-probability

While I am studying Kalman filter, I saw the following equation
P(A, B, C) = P(A, B)P(C|A)
Is this right? if right, I am wondering why this equation holds.
Thank you :)

Comment: Can you tell us where you saw this? link or reference?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know anything about Kalman filter, but the equation seems wrong to me. Should it be like this?

$P(A \cap B \cap C) = P(A \cap B)P(C|A \cap B)$

Comment: I am not sure that equation is right. Thank you :)